# Different canbus modules can work together?

Tags: stm32, integrated-circuit, can

Can ı use different canbus modules(vp230 and mcp2561) transmit and receive, respectively.

long: I set up can transciever side vp230 based longan module(https://docs.longan-labs.cc/1030001/) with arduıno nano. For receiver side ı set up mcp2561 with stm32f407. But nothing data flow.

ps: I set up mcp2561 for both side(tx and rx) with smt32, it worked.

Thanks.

Comment: CAN is a standard protocol. The whole idea of having a standard is to have different implementations of it to work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I tried your link but it is all blacked out and I cannot read it. It is irrelevant who the manufacture of the controller and or micro is, if set up properly they will work. Messages etc are not all the same, different systems can and do have different meanings for each message. You need to know that so you can understand the message.

The CAN bus is in a way like a group of people each from a different country. In order for them to communicate error free with each other they need to talk the same language at a reasonable sound level and rate. They can see each other even though they cannot communicate.

The CAN system is like that, they all need to be using the same protocol and bit rate. If one is using 250K bits and another is using 300K bits they will not be able to talk correctly but will hear the others saying something just not understanding what is being said. Because they do not understand they post an error and try again and not acknowledge the speaker. In the room the loudest person (dominate speaker) is the one who’s message will be understood by all assuming all understand the language used. When somebody understands they acknowledge to the speaker they understand what was said. CAN does that but on a digital level on the bus, this is controlled by dominance and recessiveness.

This works by each node when sending monitors the bus while it is sending to see if its message gets on the buss on a bit by bit basis. If a unit sends a recessive bit and it receives a dominate bit it backs of and waits for a while and tries again, it is not what it sent. If it sees what it is sending it keeps on going. The message is normally identified by the time the identifier has been sent and only the dominate unit is sending.  The end result is the dominate message gets through the others try again.

It works like this on the bus: for simplicity assume we have one wire with a pull up resistor. Each unit watches this wire and when sending it leaves it high when sending a 1 and pulls it down (like an open collector transistor) when it is sending a dominate zero. It bails out when sending a 1 and it sees a zero. This allows many on the bus and each can talk whenever they want making the zero dominate.

This was developed many years ago (about 1985) and was implemented many times by small 8-bit microprocessors. All of the work needed to monitor and control the bus was a daunting task for the small micro so they designed a controller taking care of that overhead. Remember there is filtering and many other things going on in the controller before it tells the micro it has something.

You can download the CAN 2.0 specification from: http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The CAN (Controlled Area Network) is well defined. It was originally developed by Bosch and adopted by many others including the Automotive, industrial, home automation and many others. There is nothing stating what brand of controller to use. Also there is nothing that states what the message has to contain, just how many bits it must send. The message and format is defined by the application. The application/system design defines the baud (bit) rate the bus will use to communicate. This can be upwards of a million bits a second but it is imperative all units on the bus use the same bit rate. If they are not the same it will not work. Bus termination is critical and is generally the most problematic item to new users next to ground (reference point).

There are two variations in common use, the original standard uses an 11 bit identifier later because more data had to be transferred they developed the 29 bit identifier. Both can also be on the same bus. Regardless they work on the same hardware principle, every message must be acknowledged. With this stated that tells us there must be at least two units on the bus, one to send the other to ACK (acknowledge) the message. It uses non destructive arbitration where the message of higher priority gets through. This is controlled by the dominance and recessiveness of the bus. The controller has an error counter and if its message is not acknowledged it counts down and tries again until it has been sent or counted out.

There are many tutorials on CAN using the Arduino and other microprocessors, watching a few of them will be a big help to you. You might also want to watch a few on the protocol proper. Bosch has published its specifications and they are available for the download.

Comment: Thanks for detailed info. Can arduıno and stm32 communicate each other via canbus? ı found this questions but not properly answered yet.  1-https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BxwtLRSQY/can-bus-between-stm32f103-and-arduino   2-https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkfAjSAJ/stm32f4-arduino-uno-can-bus-comminication-error